# u flag with ps command

Tags: command-line

According to the Mac man page for `ps` it says for the `-u` flag:

```
-u      Display the processes belonging to the specified usernames.
```

However, it seems to display different information rather than just being attached to usernames. E.g. here's the headers for `ax`:

```
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
```

and here are the headers for `aux`:

```
USER              PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
```

Any idea why? Is the man page incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

They're both sort of correct. There's a difference between `ps u` and `ps -u`. Consider:

```
$ ps -u blm
  UID   PID TTY           TIME CMD
  502  4278 ??         0:00.04 sshd: blm@ttys000
  ...

$ ps u blm
ps: illegal argument: blm
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-u]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
```

Also:

```
$ ps aux
USER              PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
root                1   1.9  0.1  2455856   4648   ??  Ss   Wed05PM   2:52.80 /
...

$ ps -aux
ps: No user named 'x'
```

The man page documents the options preceded by `-`, but ps (for compatibility with other Unix flavors) also takes options without a preceding `-`, with often completely different meanings.

In the manual page, go down to `LEGACY DESCRIPTION` for more information.